# sending objects to a callback function as a parameter- nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am implementing a `http server` for some project.

I have an `HttpServer` object that I created that contains in it a server (net module)

this server contains allot of info, and i want to pass it as parameter to the callback functions. like you would do with "`setTimeout`"

```
var time=setTimeout(function(**a**){do somthing}, 2000, **someObject**);
```

I tried doing something like that in my code but it does not recognize the parameter I passed as an object

```
var net = require('net');

function HttpServer(port){
    this.port=port;
}

HttpServer.prototype.start = function (){
    console.log("starting the server");
    this.server = net.createServer(function (socket,server) {
        console.log("my port is: "+server.port)
        socket.on('data',function(dat){  });
                                                 },this);
        //i am trying to send to the createserver callback function
        //the parameter 'this' that actually is an HttpServer
        //and  the callback function secives it as 'server' 
        //when i run the program i get an error that server is
        //undefiend and therefor does not have a member port

    this.server.listen(this.port);
}

var httpserver= new HttpServer(4444);
httpserver.start();
```

Why it does not recognize the parameter sent?

Comment: If you are trying to pass an object it should not be inside the 'start' function of your web server. You should pass it using GET/POST and then you will get the object/json back in the response.

Comment: but that is not what i want to do...
i the server it self needs that object regardless to what method/request it is given

Comment: Got it... I think you just got the right answer from @davin.

Comment: Nah, I didn't actually look at the code, I totally misread the brackets. My answer doesn't do anything... I'm not sure what the OP is trying to do here, but that parameter looks out of place...

Comment: @user1087995, not sure what you're trying to do, but google `bind`. You can also achieve similar results with traditional utilisation of the statical scoping of the language.

Comment: Also, check the docs, I'm not sure you're using `createServer` correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var net = require('net');

function HttpServer(port){
    this.port=port;
}

HttpServer.prototype.start = function (){
    console.log("starting the server");
    var that = this;    //Store this to that variable
    this.server = net.createServer(function (socket, server) {
        console.log('Server port is: ' + that.port); // Use that in an anonymous function
        socket.on('data',function(dat){  });
    });
    this.server.listen(this.port);

}


var httpserver= new HttpServer(4444);
httpserver.start();
```

Comment: I wrote almost the exact answer, but I think you misread the brackets like me. Look closely at the brackets. `that` and `this` are in the same scope, so that doesn't change anything... I.e. `that` isn't actually scoped in the anonymous function.